# Is there a way to make a gradient based on an object or a image texture?

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural, mathematics

I made this image with a monkey head and I want to be able to make something like the second image with nodes procedurally [i made this just by duplicating a cutout]
[image]

[image]

I want to be able to take a spherical gradient, or the result of the vector math length function, then use an object or a image like the first one above and make a gradient that has a value of zero at the center and 1 at the edge of the object/mask image. Making the rainbow pattern procedurally is not part of the question btw that's just easier then trying to draw the gradient.

Comment: Are you open to do that in the compositor as a post production effect ?

Comment: i recommend answering yes to Gorgious - he know what he is doing ;)

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, that works for what I'm doing, I could render it by itself because its just going to be a background anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the *Dilate / Erode* node in the Compositor Editor. [Link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/dilate_erode.html)

First setup your Object as needed and render the image.

[image]

Now you can play with several dilate / erode nodes to get the desired effect. It basically creates a dilated mask for each subsequent dilation and we're adding them , then dividing by the number of dilations, then plugging it into a Combine HSVA node to get rainbow colors. You can tweak it to get desired colors too.

[image]

There is a Distance and a Step mode in the Dilate / Erode node. I found the Distance mode to be more pleasing, but the compositing time will skyrocket on high values.

[image]

Comment: simply great!!!!